# AJAX and JS, Cannot read JSON data?

Tags: javascript, php, ajax, json

I have the following AJAX code:

```
var ajax = new XMLHttpRequest();
axaj.open("POST", "index.php", true);
ajax.setRequestHeader("Content-type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");

ajax.onreadystatechange = function(){
    if(x.readyState == 4 && x.status == 200){
        var returnVal = ajax.responseText;
    }
}

ajax.send("nextMax=-1");
```

And pairs with some PHP that ends with:

```
echo json_encode(array(
    'next_id' => $nextID
));

exit();
```

This all works, as it is. If I print out `returnVal` inside the AJAX call, it prints out the correct array, with the correct value:

```
{"next_id":"935210077606657948"}
```

But I cannot access the id directly. I've tried

```
var nextID = returnVal.next_id;
```

and

```
var nextID = returnVal['next_id'];
```

and other variations, but all return `undefined`.

How do I get the array elements from within `returnVal`?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found a solution not 30 seconds after posting the question. But for those who are in the same place:

Switch

```
var returnVal = ajax.responseText;
```

to

```
var returnVal = JSON.parse(ajax.responseText);
```

and then the call works:

```
returnVal.next_id;
```